# Perl WWW::Mechanize Parse Content issue?

Tags: perl, www-mechanize

I am using WWW::Mechanize library from Perl to scrape the content from a website. However, I noticed that the original HTML Source Code of the web page and what is parsed by WWW::Mechanize, differ. As a result of this, some of the functionality in my script gets broken.

So, here is the script (a subset, just to demonstrate the error/issue)

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use WWW::Mechanize;
use warnings;

$mech=WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->stack_depth(0);

$url="http://www.example.com";

$mech->get($url);

print $mech->content;
```

Short and simple code, it will connect to the website and retrieve the entire HTML page.

I run the script and redirect the output to a text file so that I can analyze them.

```
perl test.pl >> source_code.txt
```

Now, when I compare the source_code.txt and the actual source code of the website as displayed by the Browser (Firefox), there are differences.

For instance:

```
<tr>
<td nowrap="nowrap">This is Some Text</td>
<td align="right"><a href="http://example.com?value=key">Some more Text</a></td>
</tr><tr>
```

The above source code is what is observed in the Browser. (View Page Source Feature)

However, in the text file, source_code.txt (generated by WWW::Mechanize)

it shows:

```
<tr>
<td nowrap="nowrap">This is some text</td>
<td align="right">This is some more text</td>
</tr><tr>
```

As you can see, the anchor tag which was nested between the second set of  tags was deleted.

Is this is a known issue or do I Need to use some thing else other than $mech->content to view the source code?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd check first if the User-Agent makes a difference to the content as returned by the server. What happens if you add `agent => 'Windows IE 6'` to the `new()` call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common behavior known as ["user agent sniffing"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent#User_agent_sniffing), for example for blind users a page will be displayed differently. You can change your user agent strings in the browser with different plugins and also as @[LHMathies](https://stackoverflow.com/users/582206/lhmathies) said, in WWW::Mechanize see [UserAgent.pm](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-6.04/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm) and [Mechanize->new](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/WWW-Mechanize-1.72/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm#new%28%29)

Example :

```
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new( agent => 
     'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 9.0; en-US)' 
);
```

see also [a list of common user agent strings](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php).

Comment: There's also the `->agent_alias()` method, although those aliases haven't been updated in a long time. http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm#$mech-%3Eagent_alias%28_$alias_%29

Comment: Thank you. I will try with the User Agent.